# Brightness Keys in Dell N4010 (14R) causing freezes

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard, laptop, dell

The brightness keys on my Dell N4010 with Ubuntu 12.04 is causing ubuntu to freeze on a black screen if i press the BrightUp and BrightDown key(s) 3-4 times. I think this is a bug which was noticed in 10.04 and was patched, but its giving problem in 12.04 again to me. I tried remapping and disabling the brightness keys but it did not work out. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Edit "*/etc/default/grub*" as root.

```
gksu gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Now, look for the line that looks like:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Append "*acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi=Linux*" to the end of that line, before the end quotes, so that the line now looks something like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi=Linux"
```

Save and close the file, and run the following command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Now, reboot, and test out the brightness keys. They should be working correctly now.

Comment: This worked before, on my ubuntu 12.10. Not working anymore on ubuntu 13.04.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get this bug solved!

The answer is here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2181534&p=12819813#post12819813

Create the file /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf with the following content:

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier  "card0"
        Driver      "intel"
        Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
        BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"

EndSection
```

Log out to see if it works.